# Why my iPhone BLE scanner not detecting Some of the BLE devices, which are detected by android BLE scanner

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

Why my iPhone BLE scanner not detecting Some of the BLE devices, which are detected by android BLE scanner, is it the fault of BLE device

Comment: You should show your code. You can also check with the LightBlue app from the App Store.

Comment: Totally agree with LightBlue on this. Gold standard for detecting devices, and what I use to verify what my apps are doing. But there are far too many factors to answer this question. It depends on how you're scanning, for how long, whether the devices use Apple-recommended advertising intervals (and more generally what the advertising interval is), whether the antenna is busy, and a dozen other factors such as the specifics of how you've performed the test.

Comment: Just a blind guess, the undetected devices are iBeacons as CoreBluetooth will not return any iBeacon in scan result. On a side note, I suggest using nRF Connect on Android as an alternative tool to LightBlue, especially if you are working with any BLE Mesh Network.